# Hibernate findByexample Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm

I have two table User and Address Table

And their relation in HBM is

```
<!-- bi-directional one-to-one association to Address -->
    <one-to-one
        name="user"
        class="address"
        outer-join="auto"
    />
```

So when I set Address Pojo in User Pojo and call findByExample for User Pojo.

It ignore the Address Pojo

Answer (score 2):

The [reference manual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-examples) says:

> Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored.

But it also says:

> You can even use examples to place criteria upon associated objects.

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Example.create(cat) )
    .createCriteria("mate")
        .add( Example.create( cat.getMate() ) )
    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Associations are ignored as stated in the hibernate reference:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples